# Vaadin Chart- Hide the legend

Tags: hide, vaadin, legend

How can I hide the legend in the Vaadin Charts.
I tried commenting the legend defined in the program

```
    Legend legend = new Legend();
    legend.setLayout(LayoutDirection.VERTICAL);
    legend.setBackgroundColor(new SolidColor("#FFFFFF"));
    legend.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.BOTTOM);
    legend.setShadow(true);
    conf.setLegend(legend);
```

After commenting this, only a colour button remains on the graph.

Comment: [Here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/charts/java-api/charts-configuration.html#charts.configuration.legend) I found that you can disable the legend

Answer (score 3):

```
configuration.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
```