# Vaadin charts hiding series and it's legend

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-charts

I want to hide a chart series and it's legend in my Vaadin chart.  I know I can hide the series with `series.setVisible(false)`, but I cannot figure out how to hide the corresponding legend.

Vaadin 7
Vaadin charts 3.3.1

I tried `series.setVisible(false)`.  This does hide the data points for this series in the chart, but the legend for this series is still down below the chart.

Also, I looked online, and I see examples for hiding the legend entirely, but not hiding the legend of just one series.  As an example, [text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50851942/3329922) tells me how to hide the legend entirely, which is NOT what I want.  I also searched for `highcharts` references, since I am pretty sure Vaadin uses that under the hood.  I thought it might trigger an idea.  I did not find anything obvious.